# How to change from normal machine learning technique to cross validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X = data['Review']

y = data['Category']

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))

classifier = LinearSVC()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)

clf =  Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', tfidf),
    ('clf', classifier)
])

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))


accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

This is the code to train a model and prediction. I need to know my model performance. so where should I change to become cross_val_score?

Comment: And how to print each cross validation result using classification_report(y_test, y_pred)??

Comment: 1) There is not a "normal" ML technique 2) please take some time to learn how to properly format you code. 3) do not use the comments to update questions - edit & update the question instead.

Comment: hi, ok, It is my first time doing this. Sorry and Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:(it is an example from my previous project)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score

kfolds = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
def cv_f1(model, X, y):
  score = np.mean(cross_val_score(model, X, y,
                                scoring="f1",
                                cv=kfolds))
  return (score)


model = ....

score_f1 = cv_f1(model, X_train, y_train)
```

you can have multiple scoring. you should just change scoring="f1".
if you want to see score for each fold just remove np.mean

Answer (score 0):

from sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

> The simplest way to use cross-validation is to call the cross_val_score helper function on the estimator and the dataset.

In your case it will be

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
print(scores)
```

Comment: is the cross_val_score substitude to the clf.fix(x,y) function?

Comment: Yes, you don't need the `fit` function anymore, since `cross_val_score ` fits your model with different partitions from your data and tests with the remaining partitions

Comment: ok thankyou.  may I know how to print each classification_report in each cross validation experiment??